# AndroidJUnit4 :- GrantPermissionRule not working to allow runtime permission for the Unit test?

Tags: android, junit4, android-espresso, android-testing

I am writing the AndroidJUnit4 test case for my Broadcast Receiver class , In which there is Runtime permission for the Location and Phone State to execute some piece of code. What i need that i need to give the Runtime permission by using the GrantPermissionRule .

Please check the below exception which i am getting now

> I/TestRunner: started: testOnReceive(com.xxx.xxxxx.receiver.MyClassTest)
> I/UiAutomationShellCmd: Requesting permission: pm grant com.xxxxx.test android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
> E/GrantPermissionCallable: Permission: android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION cannot be granted!
> E/TestRunner: failed: testOnReceive(com.xxxx.xxx.receiver.MyClassTest)
> ----- begin exception -----
> E/TestRunner: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Failed to grant permissions, see logcat for details
> at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
> at androidx.test.runner.permission.PermissionRequester.requestPermissions(PermissionRequester.java:111)
> at androidx.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule$RequestPermissionStatement.evaluate(GrantPermissionRule.java:128)
> at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
> at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:154)
> at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
> at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
> at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
> at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
> at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
> at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:395)
> at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2084)
> ----- end exception -----
> I/TestRunner: finished: testOnReceive(com.xx.xxxxx.receiver.MyClassTest)
> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Failed to grant permissions, see logcat for details
> at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
> at androidx.test.runner.permission.PermissionRequester.requestPermissions(PermissionRequester.java:111)
> at androidx.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule$RequestPermissionStatement.evaluate(GrantPermissionRule.java:128)
> at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
> at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:154)
> at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
> at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
> at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
> at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
> at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
> at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:395)
> at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2084)

And Please check my code in which I am using the GrantPermissionRule like below

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule;
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry;
import androidx.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule;


import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

/**
 * MyClass Tester.
 *
 * @author <Authors name>
 * @version 1.0
 * @since <pre>Nov 5, 2020</pre>
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MyClassTest {

    private Context context;
    private MyClass test;



    @Rule public GrantPermissionRule permissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);



    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception {

        context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();

        test = new MyClass();
        System.out.print(getClass().getSimpleName() + " test start");
    }

    @After
    public void after() throws Exception {
        System.out.print(getClass().getSimpleName() + " test end");
    }

    /**
     * Method: onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
     */
    @Test
    public void testOnReceive() throws Exception {
        //TODO: Test goes here...

        if (SdkAppHelper.getInstance(context).isPermissionsAllowed()) {
            test.onReceive(context, new Intent().setAction(SdkAppConstants.ACTION_START_1));
            test.onReceive(context, new Intent().setAction(SdkAppConstants.ACTION_UPLOAD_11111_DATA_MANUALLY));
            test.onReceive(context, new Intent().setAction(SdkAppConstants.ACTION_INITIALIZE_DEVICE_ID));
        }
    }

}
```